# Displaying gifv with react

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to view the imgur format gifv for a while but i just cant seem to get it working.

Been testing with img tags, video tags, iframes. So far only the iframe seems to work - but i cant resize the iframe due to browser limitations.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/rCkPdZm.gifv" /> - nope
<video src="http://i.imgur.com/rCkPdZm.gifv"/> - nope
```

Any tips on how to display for example `http://i.imgur.com/rCkPdZm.gifv`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `gifv` is not an image format, it's a made-up "extension" to make the landing page look like you have opened an image link directly, while being able to stream video instead of a much larger gif file. Use the "view source" option and go find out! :)

You can right-click on the gifv "image" and the browser should give you an option to "copy video url", which you can then use in a `<video>` element:

`<video src="http://i.imgur.com/rCkPdZm.mp4" />`

https://jsfiddle.net/xc4cqoh5/

In this context it doesn't matter if it's React or just plain HTML website, the solution is the same: you need to grab the URL of the actual video being played, not the `gifv` page that embeds it. It seems you can just replace the `.gifv` extension with `.mp4`. To make this answer relevant to the `reactjs` tag here's an example:

```
const Player = props => {
   let videourl = props.videourl.replace('.gifv', '.mp4');
   return <video src={ videourl } />;
};

ReactDOM.render( <Player videourl="http://i.imgur.com/rCkPdZm.gifv" />,
 document.getElementById('container'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47077/

Comment: Oh god, i tried changing the extension to webm and it didnt work (found webm in the source) But mp4 works! Thats mildly infuriating :) Thanks for the help!